# Cannot set id of a fragment in Android

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I am having a problem trying to give my Fragments an id within the XML, however I cannot seem to be able to do that.  I tried following tutorials, but the id seems to not be set to the fragment.  I'm using the swipe + sections template that is supplied.  Here is my xml for the main activity:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!--
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
titles for adjacent pages.

-->

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<Fragment
    android:id="@+id/account_information_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.AccountInformationFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and then in my fragment class I use this to set up the layout:

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_information_layout, container, false);
```

And that layout doesn't contain any  tags.  Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. You can't get a reference to your fragment? Or you can't get a reference to items within your fragment?

Comment: I tried doing this.getIt() inside the AccountInformationFragment class and it returns false.  I also tried using the getSupportedFragmentManger().findFragmentById(R.id.account_information_fragment) and it still return false from that fragment.  It seems as though the id isn't being set to that fragment, or it matching correctly.

Comment: Can you post all your code?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem.  First off, the Fragment tag needs to start with a lower-case F, like so:

Good:

```
<fragment>
```

Bad:

```
<Fragment>
```

Secondly, I am afraid I forgot that a Toast will return false when trying to display any non-string.  You would have to use

```
String.valueOf(fragment.getId());
```

In order for it to show in a Toast.

I have no idea why this wasn't working at first since I believe I tried both f and F for the tag earlier.  Setting an android:tag helped me debug this because that returns a string naturally.